# ‘Turns out’ usage

Tags: meaning

I’m English learner and reading *The Martian*. In there:

> Turns out, through a neat set of chemical reactions with the Martian atmosphere, for every kilogram of hydrogen you bring to Mars, you can make thirteen kilograms of fuel.

What is the meaning of “Turns out” here?

Comment: maybe, 'turn out' is something like: *the result goes like ...*

Comment: Bear in mind, not putting in a subject (It turns out that etc.) is colloquial speech and not usually a written form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**turns out** at the head of a sentence like that is an informal way of introducing a fact, and usually the fact is something *discovered*.

> Turns out, I have a cousin living in Iceland.

Formerly, the speaker did not know about this cousin.

> Turns out, I didn't leave my wallet at home after all. It was on the floor of the car.

The error was discovered. The wallet is not at home as was believed.

P.S. To "turn out" refers to the *unfolding* of facts.  Let's say you are watching a murder mystery movie but are called away to take an important phone call and it is going to take a while, so you tell your friends not to pause the movie but to continue watching. Upon your return, the movie is over. You can ask your friends

> How did it turn out?

Was the mystery solved? Who committed the murder?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out: to happen or become known to happen in a particular way:

She assured him that everything would turn out all right.
It turns out (that) Ray had borrowed the money from one of his students

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-out

So basically here it means "It is the case, that" or "the fact is".

Answer (score 0):

"It turns out that ..." is  not always informal. Indeed in my own subject, statistics, it is used frequently. What it means is, in effect, "Dear reader, please accept that after doing some mathematics that would be too complicated to go into here..."

"Turns out" as in the OP's question is just a shortened, informal, version of the formal "it turns out". An analogy would be the use of "Trouble is..." in place of the more formal "The trouble is..."